# Spring ResourceLoader load file from IDE and throw exception when load from jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, resources

I load file from resources like this:

```
@Bean
Schema schema(SchemaFactory schemaFactory) throws SAXException, IOException {
    ResourceLoader resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    Resource resource = resolver.getResource("schemas/my.xsd");
    return schemaFactory.newSchema(resource.getURL());
}
```

And this code work fine when I start server from **Intellij IDE** and from **jar**

In another class I try same code:

```
    ResourceLoader resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    Resource resource = resolver.getResource("schemas/my.wsdl");
    endpoint.setWsdlLocation(resource.getURL().toString());
```

And this code work fine when I start  server from **Intellij IDE** and **throw exception when I start from jar**

In debug mode I get url in bouth cases:

```
file:/D:/gitProjects/my-server/sources/my-generator/build/resources/main/schemas/my.xsd
file:/D:/gitProjects/my-server/sources/my-generator/build/resources/main/schemas/my.wsdl
```

If I change code to this:

```
endpoint.setWsdlLocation("jar:file:BOOT-INF/lib/my-generator.jar!/schemas/my.wsdl");
```

code work fine when I start server from **Intellij IDE** and from **jar**

**A two questions:**

1) Why when loading from an idea everything works and from jar does not?

2) How to load right?